# Question Concerning The Solution Of A Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

Here's another question from Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Greenberg [Ex 1.2 Q5]:

> For what values of the constant $\lambda$ will $y = \exp(\lambda x)$ be a solution of the differential equation? If there are no such $\lambda$'s, state that $y^\prime  + 3y = 0$

First of all, I couldn't understand the question because of the thing called $\exp$ in $y = \exp(\lambda x)$. May I know what is $\exp$? I'm confident that if I get to know what $\exp$ is then I can take it from there.

Comment: ${\rm exp}\,( x)=e^x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Why not use `\exp` instead of `{\rm exp}`?

Comment: @matt Thanks, I didn't realize that was defined already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an alternative notation for the  [exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function): $\exp (x)=e^x$. Some authors use this notation exclusively.

The notation is convenient to use if the argument of the exponential function is "large". For example, contrast $e^{(x-\mu)^2\over 2\sigma^2}$ with $\exp\Bigl({(x-\mu)^2\over 2\sigma^2}\Bigr)$. Some may find the latter notation ugly.

Comment: I would also say that it is also valuable pedagogically: it allows a student to work with it without the preconceived notions of how powers work. $e^x e^y=e^{x+y}$ is "obvious", but proving that for $\exp$ without knowing that it is indeed an exponential function is not too trivial.